# Automated third party software for Active Directory administration

Tags: active-directory, user-management, groups

I have a situation where there are multiple Active Directory (AD) groups that each account is added to but each group have different expiration dates.

For example, user1 will be in groupA and groupB. The access for groupA should expire in 1 month and groupB in 2 month. In the current setup I am only able to setup expiration for the longest access date.

Is there any software that can help track and automate the removal of these accounts (from the groups)?

I am using current using Windows Active Directory to manage users/groups.

Comment: That seems a bit counter intuitive, I might be a member of groupB so I should be able to finish projectB - but because projectA stops and groupA privileges get revoked - I can't work on projectB  anymore either. But a powershell script or equivalent that does a loop: for each groupname in ( select group-names ordered by expiry date in descending order) --> get  members from groupname and for each groupmember set account expiry to group expiry date. And let chaos ensue!

Comment: Hi HBruijn. In the example above what will happen is that access for the two projects will be given on the same date. A new expiration date is set from groupB so groupA never gets revoked. The account expires only when the groupB expiration date is set. Hoping to find a piece of software rather than powershell the task.

Comment: Just to clarify, you'd like to set a date when the user account is removed from a specific group (once this date is reached, it'll automatically remove the account)?

Comment: @JoeS Once the expiration date is reached the piece of software would remove the group access from the "Members Of" section in Active Directory.

Answer (score 2):

Quest ActiveRoles Server should cover what you're looking for. Quest ARS has a feature where you can set the expiry date for a certain user and once this date is reached, the user is automatically removed from the group.

Quest ARS also has other automated features along with an enhanced audit tool.

URL:
[Quest ActiveRoles Server Website](http://www.quest.com/activeroles-server/)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. If you have recommendation or experience from other vendors I would love to heard about it. Thank you.

Comment: I haven't had any previous experience with other applications, all the companies I've worked for previously use Quest due to the advantages and great interface on the tool (this is exactly the same as Active Directory (plus there is a web version of this rather than locally installing the tool)).  I'm sure there are other applications available however I'd strong recommend the ActiveRoles server from Quest.